# Touchscreen calibration on an LCD

Tags: linux, qt, arm, driver, touchscreen

I have a 7" 800x480 touchscreen which I had to adjust the kernel driver code for (for an ARM Cortex A9).  I managed to get it working and printk out the raw X and raw Y of my touchscreen.  It works nicely and goes from 1,1 to 800,600.

For a basic calibration I thought I would just scale 800,600 into 800x480.  After doing this and running apps in various frameworks including Qt and the x was perfect however the y wasn't working.   It works for the top half and the bottom half is just a copy of the top half.

My question is what values does (embedded) linux expect from the TS driver?  Is it the screen resolution? Or something completely different?

Tim